# In Vue / Javascript, how can I use a dynamic reference to this.$refs.someDynamicVariable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am writing a step through form and need to access the ref for each step in my Axios catch block in a DRY way.

Below, where it says `stepOneObserver`, I need `stepTwoObserver`, `stepThree`, `stepFour`, etc.

```
this.$refs.stepOneObserver.setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
```

Is it possible to use a variable for this?

```
if (observerStep === 1) {
    var obsStep = 'stepOneObserver';
}
this.$refs.{obsStep}.setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
```

I'm pseudo-coding, but basically want the `{obsStep}` to act as if it said `stepOneObserver` and reference that in the code.

Hope this is clear enough / makes sense.

Comment: `this.$refs[obsStep]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should access it using `[]` like :

```
 this.$refs[obsStep].setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
```

for more details check [`Property accessors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Use this solution, plus a switch statement to set `obsStep`, that should make for clean code.

Comment: Please try to search for duplicates instead of answering. This is an often-asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896